# How to Execute a callable a fixed number of times and have a sleep interval/delay between each execution

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice

I have a situation where i need to check if a certain condition is met and it needs to be periodically executed a certain number of times to check for the condition before it declares the condition as not met and between each execution there needs to be a delay/sleep interval.

Code Structure:

```
class checkCondition<T> implements Callable<T>{
 @Override
public T call() {
//Do Stuff and return result
return result;
}
public class TaskRunner<T> {
private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
public Future<T> runTask(checkCondiiton task, int times, long sleep){

while(times > 0){
future = executor.submit(task);
Thread.sleep(sleep);
times--;
}
return future;
}
}

}
```

Is the above implementation correct? If not, please advice on what would be better approach. I am new to ExecutorService and Java Concurrency.

Answer (score 6):

Try using Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()

Example:

```
public class FixedScheduledExcutor
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(5);
        executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyRunner(latch), 5, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        latch.await();
        System.out.println("Shutting down service...");
        executorService.shutdown();
    }
}

class MyRunner implements Runnable
{
    CountDownLatch latch;

    MyRunner(CountDownLatch latch)
    {
        this.latch = latch;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Do something : " + latch.getCount());
        latch.countDown();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is important that I return the future back, can I do this with the callable?

Comment: I feel you can have a shared ConcurrentHashMap and let all threads dump in their results in with their ID ( Or any unique ID you assign to the objects. Once the latch.wait() is released you can fetch the results. 

No, you can't do this with Callable